# Hibernate saveOrUpdate() doesn't seem to cascade creation and saving

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I'm new to Hibernate and am trying to save a "UserState" with a list of "WorkspaceState"s. UserState objects are keyed by a username that is set, the WorkspaceStates are set by UUID scheme. My issue is that if I have a UserState with one WorkspaceState in it, the UserState gets saved but the WorkspaceState does not.

Here are the Hibernate mapping

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="UserState" table="USERSTATE">
        <id name="owner" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="OWNER" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <list name="workspaces" inverse="false" cascade="all" table="WORKSPACESTATE" lazy="true">
            <key>
                <column name="UID" />
            </key>
            <list-index></list-index>
            <one-to-many class="WorkspaceState" />
        </list>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="WorkspaceState" table="WORKSPACESTATE">
        <id name="uid" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="UID" />
            <generator class="uuid" />
        </id>
        <property name="owner" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="OWNER" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I have a UserState object with one WorkspaceState in it. When I do a session.saveOrUpdate(userst), I see that hibernate has already removed the WorkspaceState from my userst object. Then the commit saves it to the DB without the workspacestate in it.

In truth the WorkspaceState themselves have lists, but I suspect whatever I'm doing wrong continues onward.

Thanks

Edit - how it's committed. HibernateUtil is as it appears in the standard hibernate document examples:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Transaction transaction = null;

try {
    transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    String username = (String) session.merge(state);
    transaction.commit();
} catch (HibernateException e) {
    transaction.rollback();
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
} finally {
    session.close();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code on how you're executing the commit?

Comment: I added a snipped to the end of the original post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you need to change cascade reference to save-update and remove inverse attribute from workspace list mapping